# Rails controller update record by copying field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 3.2 app where I would like to copy the contents of one field to another in a controller action.

`Costprojects` contains these 2 columns:

```
original_year
project_year
```

I want to copy the contents of `project_year` into `original_year`.

I tried doing this:

```
    update = Costproject.where(:id => @costprojects).update_all(:original_year => :project_year)
```

I get this error:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "project_year"
```

LINE 1: UPDATE "costprojects" SET "original_year" = 'project_year' W...

```
                                                ^
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are both columns have same datatype ? plz check

Comment: I am sure not.. use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22060851/rails-migration-pgerror-error-invalid-input-syntax-for-integer) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20715190/pginvalidtextrepresentation-error-invalid-input-syntax-for-integer-m) as a solution.

Comment: Both columns are integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this :

```
Costproject.where(:id => @costprojects)
           .update_all("original_year = project_year")
```

With your former code:

```
update_all(:original_year => :project_year)
```

It was trying to update an *integer* field `original_year` with a string value `project_year`. That's why you got the error.